# Does database implementation match the design?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Given a database design, as defined by the TSQL used to create it. Is there an easy way to check an existing database to ensure that the implementation matches that design?

All tables and columns are accounted for?

All columns are marked null or not null appropriately (the root of why I'm asking this question)?

Going further, checking primary and foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Visual Studio 2010's database project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx) or a commercial tool such as [RedGate's schema compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) to compare and synchronise schema.

Comment: Feels a bit odd to highlight RedGate's schema compare as "a commercial tool" when Visual Studio is hardly free (at least, in editions that support database projects)